# Problems with converting tkinter input to int in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a chatroom using tkinter and sockets in Python. However, when I try to convert my entry into a integer, it doesn't cast.

```py
import socket
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


HEADER = 64
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x100")

e1 = Entry(root)
e1.pack()



def connect():
    ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
    print(type(ADDR))

    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect(ADDR)

def get_entry():
    global PORT
    PORT = (e1.get())
    print(type(PORT))


btn1 = Button(root, text="Get data", command =get_entry)
btn2 = Button(root, text="Connect", command=connect)

btn1.pack()
btn2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I've tried re-programming the whole code but it still gives me the same error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please include the full error as part of your  question.

Comment: I don't see any code that tries to convert something to an integer. Try `PORT = int(e1.get())`

Comment: You could also connect an `IntVar` object to the `Entry`.

Comment: Let's pray you don't press the button `Connect` before the button `Get Data`. Otherwise the problem will crash since `PORT` is not defined until `get_entry` is executed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i am a dunce thanks it works now, i forgot the int().

Comment: Answer your own question if you solved the problem.